# How to update UITableView when a CustomCell label value changes?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell class with two buttons and one label defined in its own class.  Am using protocol-delegates to update the value of the label when the button is pressed. But am not able to figure out how to update the UITableView.

```
protocol customCellDelegate: class {
    func didTapDecrementBtn(_ sender: AllCountersTableViewCell)
    func didTapIncrementBtn(_ sender: AllCountersTableViewCell)
    func updateTableViewCell(_ sender: AllCountersTableViewCell)
}

class AllCountersTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var counterValueLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterNameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterResetDateLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var counterDecrementBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterIncrementBtn: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: customCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func decrementBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapDecrementBtn(self)
        delegate?.updateTableViewCell(self)
    }

    @IBAction func incrementBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapIncrementBtn(self)
        delegate?.updateTableViewCell(self)
    }
```

In my ViewController, I have provided the delegate. But reloadData() is not working, so although `sender.counterLbl.value` is changing its not reflecting on the view.

```
extension AllCountersVC: customCellDelegate {

    func didTapIncrementBtn(_ sender: AllCountersTableViewCell) {
        guard let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) else {return}
        let rowNoOfCustomCell = tappedCellIndexPath[1]
        let newValue = String(allCounter[rowNoOfCustomCell].incrementCounterValue(by: allCounter[rowNoOfCustomCell].counterIncrementValue))
        sender.counterValueLbl.text = newValue
    }

    func updateTableViewCell(_ sender: AllCountersTableViewCell) {
        allCountersTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRow` you must set `cell.delegate = self` for this logic to start working. Its not enough just to make you controller confroms to your custom cell delegate protocol. From your post I assume `delegate` is always `nil` in the cell, that is why it does not work.

Comment: thats done already. Am using a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController with a UITableView on top. Does that matter?